# Small push deleted and then added everything

Tags: git, github

I made a small push to a project after which every line of every file is reported as being deleted and then added again (verbatim as far as I can tell). So despite having changed only about 4 lines of code, my commit is reported as involving "156 changed files  with 10,422 additions and 10,418 deletions."

Does anyone know why this happened, and how I can avoid it in the future? Additionally, should/can I undo this push?

Comment: You probably changed line endings. Are you working on Windows?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I'm working in Windows.

Comment: Can this be undone and is there a way to avoid doing this in the future (I don't remember doing anything that should have changed all of the line endings)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always check which files you are about to commit (`git status`). You would see 157 changed files in your case.

Moreover, you might check your commit before you push to the remote
(`git show --stat` will show affected files in your last commit).